# Anybody Know how to recover an account in Superuser?

Tags: support

I last used superuser about 1 month ago.  There isn't a clear path to logging in where you enter user account and password.  Can anyone recommend a) the login/password login page for Superuser.com or b) a way to recover passwords for superuser.com?

Answer (score 1):

Superuser uses OpenID for registration which means you used an account on another service to log in (Google, Yahoo!, AOL, MyOpenID, etc). Click on the [login](https://superuser.com/users/login) link at the top of the page and select the OpenID provider you selected when you first logged in.

If you don't remember the password, go to the service provider and use their password recovery procedures. If you don't remember which OpenID provider you used, contact team@superuser.com with your account information and maybe they can tell you which OpenID provider you used.